# Rails: Is this model good for worker queues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, queue, worker

Code in question:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

    require 'Library'
    AN_ARRAY = [ 1, 2 ]
    THING = Classname.new.thing()

    def self.perform(param)
        # do stuff using THING, i.e. THING.do(something)
        do_things(param)
    end

    def self.do_things(param)
        # do stuff with AN_ARRAY and/or THING
    end

end
```

I'm not quite sure how Rails handles models. Do the top three statements execute only once? Is there only one `THING`, or might there be many `THING`s? If I queue workers to execute `self.perform()`, will things be alright as long as the state of `THING` isn't changed? Should I be initializing `THING` in the functions themselves instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the class is loaded, all the lines are evaluated by ruby once:

The following two lines define two constants since they begin with a capital letter. This means there is only one THING and one AN_ARRAY.

```
    AN_ARRAY = [ 1, 2 ]
    THING = Classname.new.thing()
```

The `def` statements below are also evaluated once and end up defining two class methods:

```
    def self.perform(param)
        # do stuff using THING, i.e. THING.do(something)
        do_things(param)
    end

    def self.do_things(param)
        # do stuff with AN_ARRAY and/or THING
    end
```

So, the methods should work as expected in your queue workers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; to clarify, is it bad to have multiple workers share one THING, or should I instantiate one for each worker?

Comment: I normally avoid this as you will have to make sure that either everything in that THING is read-only and if it get modified, it does not adversely impact some other worker using the THING at the same time. The only reason for setting up such a shared-object is if THING is very expensive to create. This scenario is quite rare, though. You are much better off creating an instance for each worker.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that's what I thought too. The `THING` I am using can get expensive, so I'll just have to experiment with these methods until I get it right.